# Strange mismatched quote problem trying to run a shell command from script console

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I’m trying to run a local shell command from the script console, and a mismatched quote error is kicking my butt. The entire command is surrounded by double quotes, and the command executed from the “-c” is surrounded by single quotes. There’s not a typo, I swear! Any ideas? The strange this is that it only seems to happen if there’s multiple items separated by spaces in the single quotes. If I do a single executable like ‘ls’, that works fine.

```
def String target_database = "testdb"
def String version = "7.6.5.4"

def sout = new StringBuffer(), serr = new StringBuffer()
def proc = "sudo su oracle -c '/home/oracle/scripts/datapump/refresh_database.sh ${target_database} ${version}'".execute()

proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
proc.waitForOrKill(1000)
println "STDOUT\n $sout"
println "STDERR\n $serr"
```

STDOUT

STDERR
 testdb: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
testdb: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovys `execute()` on a String just splits on whitespace and therefor this is only useful for very simple commands.  Always use `execute()` on an array instead:

```
def proc = ["sudo", "su", "oracle", "-c", "/home/oracle/scripts/datapump/refresh_database.sh ${target_database} ${version}"].execute()
```

Or if you prefer quoting for shells, use `["sh", "-c", "sudo ..."].execute()`

And on a side note: `sudo` has the `-u` param.

Comment: Two birds with one stone ;)